# Serial port doesn't work properly after reboot, unless I execute minicom

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial

My program begins like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from serial import Serial, EIGHTBITS, PARITY_NONE, STOPBITS_ONE

SERIAL_DEVICE = '/dev/ttyUSB0'

ser = Serial(SERIAL_DEVICE, timeout=2, baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS,
             parity=PARITY_NONE, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE)
```

The next part of the program sends something to the device and then expects a response. When I run it after reboot, it doesn't find the response it is expecting and terminates with an error (this is correct behavior apart from the fact that it doesn't see the response it expects).

However, if I run `minicom` and talk to the device through `minicom`, it works fine. If then I close `minicom` and run the program, it runs fine. The `minicom` configuration has an empty initialization string and I always exit without reset.

Needless to say, `minicom` has the same settings AFAICS. It also has hardware control on, but I did try `rtscts=True` as an argument to `Serial()` and saw no difference (and even if I had an error in the arguments, this doesn't explain why after executing `minicom` the program works properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptom you have is an indication that your program is not initializing the serial terminal to the proper mode that it requires.

> minicom has the same settings AFAICS

Seems like you choose to guess rather than gather actual data.
Use `stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0` before and after using **minicom**.
The major difference is that the termios mode is probably canonical by default (after the reboot), and **minicom** leaves it in non-canonical mode.

Try using `stty raw -F /dev/ttyUSB0` before starting your program.

Comment: Thanks. With your suggestions I determined that the culprit was HUPCL. I modified the program, and it now checks if HUPCL is on; if it is, it turns it off, and then closes and re-opens the port.